# Retrieve XML attributes of a view in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'd like to implement a custom Preference with an icon and be able to define the source of the  icon in the XML specification of the view. If I do

```
<com.example.MyIconPreference
    android:src="@drawable/icon1"
    android:key="test_key"
    android:title="@string/pref_title"
    android:summary="@string/pref_summary"
></com.example.MyIconPreference>
```

How can I retrieve programmatically the drawable resource or identifier?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is identical to how you can define your custom `View` and custom `View` attributes. The mechanism is the same.

You can find an example with `View` here: [Creating Custom Views](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/08/creatingcustomviews/).

Answer (score 0):

Define it similar to a custom view and retrieve attributes in you implementation.

This question discuss how to do this for custom views: [Declaring a custom android UI element using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml)