# (Vibrating TextView) Configure attributes for custom views

Tags: android

I just created class `VibratingTextView`. I intend to create a whole library of widgets so I want to do it the right way.

The xml for this View:

```
<sherif.android.textview.VibratingTextView  
    android:id="@+id/textView2"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:orientation="horizontal"  
    android:text="outToRight" >  
</sherif.android.textview.VibratingTextView>
```

Notice it has `android:orientation` and `android:text`. It accepts the attributes of a `TextView` and of a `LinearLayout`. The class itself `extends LinearLayout`.

My problem is in the xml editor of eclipse. When the user types `android:`, eclipse's intellisense gives the user the options available in this namespace.

In my case, it is giving the attributes of `LinearLayout` so, for example, `Text` and `TextSize` do not appear.

Is there a way to make them appear (using the `android` namespace)?

If not, should I create my own namespace with attributes that I define? or is there a way to import the android's attributes and make them in sherif's attributes?

Keep in mind that I am creating a TextView in the constructor of my class using the attributes passed. It is working fine and all the attributes for the TextView are being set correctly.

Since I will create many other widgets, I might need my own namespace but what is the best practice? For example, I want to create `alwaysVibrate` attribute. It will be something like `sherif:alwaysVibrate="true"`. I want my library to be includable and eclipse to show the attributes of my namespace: I use the usual way using `attr.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently faced the exact same problem. Here are my custom attribute declarations in `attrs.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="NumberPicker">
        <attr name="rangeStart" format="integer|reference" />
        <attr name="rangeEnd" format="integer|reference" />
        <attr name="speed" format="integer|reference" />
        <attr name="current" format="integer|reference" />
        <attr name="android:orientation" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

You can reuse the android attributes but you can't teach them to suggest different values. In fact you can't even teach eclipse to suggest your custom attribute definitions (at least at this date of post, I would love to see that feature in future).

Everything else you would want to know about defining custom attributes is in the question:
[Declaring a custom android UI element using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml/2695649#2695649).

Comment: By the way: upvote from me for the very cool looking effect of your custom view and your willing to share that with us!

Comment: +1 but I really hate bad news :P! I hope someone has a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty although I didn't respond in the bounty timespan!

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Tried to use the solution form the answer but in my case Android Studio suggested the following: app:android:orientation (since "app" is my custom namespace). Is there a way to workaround that behavior so Android Studio suggests "android:orientation" instead?