# How can I add a vibrate event to the onLongClick() method?

Tags: java, android

How can I add a vibrate event to the `onLongClick()` method?

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {  some case here    }   TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(v.getid()); ....                                                                                     } //i want to add a vibrate event to the textview  .But i have a mistake,did you know how to do?thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your onLongClick listener use this

```
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(1000);
```

Add this permission to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: but i want the specified TextView to vibrate instead of the whole device to vibrate when i click it ,i think android device support it

Comment: http://sherifandroid.blogspot.in/2011/09/vibratingtextview.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512124/vibrating-textview-configure-attributes-for-custom-views