# Android - custom UI with custom attributes

Tags: android, custom-controls

I know it is possible to create custom UI element (by way of View or specific UI element extension). But is it possible to define new properties or attributes to newly created UI elements (I mean not inherited, but brand new to define some specific behavior I am not able to handle with default propertis or attributes)

e.g. element my custom element:

```
<com.tryout.myCustomElement
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Element..."
   android:myCustomValue=<someValue>
/>
```

So is it possible to define **MyCustomValue**?

Thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml

Comment: Hey here you have some nice article about the custom attributes in android - https://amcmobileware.org/android/blog/2016/09/11/custom-attributes/

Comment: Have a look at my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs/25648349#25648349) related question.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Yes. Short guide:

1. Create an attribute XML

---

Create a new XML file inside `/res/values/attrs.xml`, with the attribute and its type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyCustomElement">
        <attr name="distanceExample" format="dimension"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Basically you have to set up one `<declare-styleable />` for your view that contains all your custom attributes (here just one). I never found a full list of possible types, so you need to look at the source for one I guess. Types that I know are *reference (to another resource), color, boolean, dimension, float, integer and string*. They are pretty self-explanatory

2. Use the attributes in your layout

---

That works the same way you did above, with one exception. Your custom attribute needs its own XML namespace.

```
<com.example.yourpackage.MyCustomElement
   xmlns:customNS="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.yourpackage"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Element..."
   customNS:distanceExample="12dp"
   />
```

Pretty straight forward.

3. Make use of the values you get passed

---

Modify the constructor of your custom view to parse the values.

```
public MyCustomElement(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
        
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyCustomElement, 0, 0);
    try {
        distanceExample = ta.getDimension(R.styleable.MyCustomElement_distanceExample, 100.0f);
    } finally {
        ta.recycle();
    }
    // ...
}
```

`distanceExample` is a private member variable in this example. `TypedArray` has lots of other things to parse other types of values.

And that's it. Use the parsed value in your `View` to modify it, e.g. use it in `onDraw()` to change the look accordingly.

Comment: Just note about TypedArray. Be sure to call recycle() when done with them.

Comment: Here you can find a good list https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml

Comment: Does the IDE (eclipse for example) auto-complete the keys/values of custom attributes?

Comment: @kilaka I know that android studio does, it auto-completes custom enum types and knows that you're using @string/ and @dimen/ resource names and auto-completes them also.

Comment: for gradle builds you should use `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` when declaring the custom namespace

Comment: Create a new XML file inside /res/values/attrs.xml.... how to insert a file into a file?

Comment: @Dagon I think he meant create declare-styleable tag if the attrs.xml exists. If not, create a new xml file

Comment: I got a message: `In Gradle Project, always use https://schema.android.com/apk/res-auto for custom attributes`

Comment: In step 3, you can simply use `String initialText = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", "initialText");` where attr is the AttributeSet that is passed in the constructor and 'initialText' is your custom attribute name

Comment: [https://chaosinmotion.blog/2009/01/19/valid-format-values-for-declare-styleableattr-tags/https://chaosinmotion.blog/2009/01/19/valid-format-values-for-declare-styleableattr-tags/https://chaosinmotion.blog/2009/01/19/valid-format-values-for-declare-styleableattr-tags/https://chaosinmotion.blog/2009/01/19/valid-format-values-for-declare-styleableattr-tags/https://chaosinmotion.blog/2009/01/19/valid-format-values-for-declare-styleableattr-tags/]  A full list of Atts types. I thought of posting for you, as you said you never found a full list.

Answer (score 22):

In your res/values folder create attr.xml. There you can define your attribues:

```
<declare-styleable name="">
    <attr name="myCustomValue" format="integer/boolean/whatever" />
</declare-styleable>
```

When you then want to use it in your layout file you have to add

```
xmlns:customname="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.package.name"
```

and then you can use the value with `customname:myCustomValue=""`

Comment: this is not the answer, the question is how to programatically change from java

Answer (score -14):

Yes , you can.Just use `<resource>` tag.
like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[link from official website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But in resource, i see using default "android:" values. My point is, can I have e.g. android:phoneNameSelected="true" as a parameter of my custom UI element?