# Custom ActionProvider with custom attributes

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, android-attributes

Creating custom attributes for a custom `View` is fairly [straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608464/android-custom-ui-with-custom-attributes). As is creating a [custom `ActionProvider`](https://gist.github.com/f2prateek/3982054). The difficulty is that the `ActionProvider` class constructor only has a `Context` argument and no `AttributeSet` argument, like a custom `View` would have. Is there any other way to access the custom attributes from within the constructor, e.g. can I get access to the `AttributeSet` object by some other means? Or any other approach to adding custom attributes to a custom `ActionProvider`? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "Is there any other way to access the custom attributes from within the constructor" -- do you mean in the menu resource? If so, I think that requires a custom `MenuInflater`.

Comment: The `LayoutInflator` class has a `getFactory()` method, which has method `onCreateView(..., AttributeSet attrs)`. So maybe I can override that?

Comment: OK, let's try asking it this way: what "custom attributes" are you referring to? What file would they be in? Where would this file be used? For example, in your linked-to `ActionProvider` gist, they have a menu resource (referring to the provider) and a layout resource (for the provider implementation itself). Which of those would contain your desired custom attributes?

Comment: In the menu resource, each item could specify a custom attribute.

Comment: Then a `LayoutInflater` factory will not help you, as a `LayoutInflater` is not involved with inflating menus.

Comment: So I definitely will need a `MenuInflator`. But I don't have access to that within the `ActionProvider` subclass

Comment: No, but the `MenuInflater` is involved in creating the instance of the `ActionProvider` itself. The `MenuInflater` could conceivably read the custom attributes, then pass them to the `ActionProvider` by calling setter methods.

Comment: Unfortunately `MenuInflater` only exposes the method `inflate` though.