# android including one layout with different IDs

Tags: java, android, include

I have created a layout with an ImageView, I want to include it two times with two different ImageView 
like a ListView with different positions.

**this is the ImageView layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/main_guilds_item"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/main_guilds_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

here i include the layout two times but i want to access those ImageViews with different IDs to set different Images.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/main_guilds_item"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/main_guilds_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Please share the code you already have, and if possible a (simple and small) image of what you want to achieve. That way it's easier for the rest of us to help you.

Comment: The two codeblocks you've added are the same. Could you include the 'main_guilds_item' xml layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom view for this purpose. Steps are

1. Create a xml file of the view `my_custom_view.xml`

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/image_view"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       />
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Then you need to create a class `ItemList` that extends RelativeLayout(the parent layout in your my_custom_view.xml)

   ```
   public class ItemList extends RelativeLayout {

   ImageView mImageView;

   public ItemList(Context context) {
   this(context, null);
   }

   public ItemList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   this(context, attrs, 0);
   }

   public ItemList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
   super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_content, this);
        mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
   }

   public void setImage(Drawable imageId){
   mImageView.setImageDrawable(imageId);
   }
   }
   ```
3. Then you can use this customview in your other layouts as many times as you want like below

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <yourpackage.ItemList
           android:id="@+id/first_view"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
       </yourpackage.ItemList>

       <yourpackage.ItemList
           android:id="@+id/second_view"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
       </yourpackage.ItemList>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
4. Now from your class you do

   ```
   ItemList firstItem=(ItemList) findViewById(R.id.first_view);
   ItemList secondItem=(ItemList) findViewById(R.id.second_view);
   firstItem.setImage(R.drawable.your_image);
   secondItem.setImage(R.drawable.your_image_2);
   ```

**NOTE:**
You can also take the image from xml. In that case you will have to use custom attribute. Follow the link for that purpose.
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/7608739/3975838