# How to pass the value of layout width/height to custom view class

Tags: android, android-layout, declare-styleable

I am creating a module having a class (roundbutton) extending linear layout. It contains an image view and a textview.

When the roundbutton  view is declared in the XML file, a layout_width and layout_height values are assigned. I want the imageview dimensions to be proportional to the layout dimensions assigned.  Hence how to pass the layout dimensions to the view class so that I can assign the proportional dimensions to the image view?

P.S.: This question does not deal with passing custom attributes. But deals with passing the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to the custom UI Class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - custom UI with custom attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608464/android-custom-ui-with-custom-attributes)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of that. I am not talking about custom attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by passing the instance of the view to the method that requires the values. And then use `getViewTreeObserver().OnGlobalLayoutListener()`.

```
public void setIcon(final RoundedButton rb, final int drawableResourceId, final int position){
    mIconPosition = position;

    rb.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            buttonWidth = rb.getWidth();
            buttonHeight = rb.getHeight();

            //whatever needs to be done with the dimensions
        }
    });
}
```

You cannot do `this.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` even if the class extends a type of view.