# How to remove the namespace android:

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <TextView
        android:text="VIP List"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Kunal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Kagure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Lyla"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how a typical layout looks like in Android, so I see all the `android:` are redundant, I understand that the purpose of the namespace is disambiguate the elements, so is there a way if I just write `text = "Name"`, it will be interpreted as `android:text = "Name"` by setting some global default perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

android xml need this element (android:...) Because some libraries need to use (app:...), or even you create custom view and personal custom attribute for view.

you can see custom view by Defining custom attrs this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7608739/4797289).