# Android custom drop down view with dynamic list

Tags: java, android, xml, mvvm, dropdown

I have a problem with filling `android:entries` with `String[]` from my `ViewModel`. Code looks like that:

**attrs.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="AutoCompleteDropDown">
    <attr name="android:entries" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**My custom dropdown, AutoCompleteDropDown**

```
public class AutoCompleteDropDown extends AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView {

    public AutoCompleteDropDown(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attributes, R.styleable.AutoCompleteDropDown, 0, 0);
        CharSequence[] entries = a.getTextArray(R.styleable.AutoCompleteDropDown_android_entries);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, entries);
        setAdapter(adapter);
    }
...
```

**ViewModel**

```
...
private String[] genders;

public String[] getGenders() {
    return genders;
}

public void setGenders(String[] genders) {
    this.genders = genders;
}
...
```

`genders` are filled in `ViewModel` constructor:

`genders = dataRepository.getGenders();`

**xml file**

```
<AutoCompleteDropDown
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={vm.title}"
    android:entries="@{vm.genders}"
    bind:addTextChangedListener="@{vm.titleValidationChangeListener}"/>
```

`ViewModel` is binded correctly, i'm using it many times in that xml file. When i try to run the app i'm getting:

> Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:entries' with parameter
>   type java.lang.String[] on AutoCompleteDropDown

It works when i use `android:entries="@array/genders"` but i need this list to be dynamic. Project is in MVVM pattern. Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BindingAdapter` for this. Like :

```
@BindingAdapter("entries")
public static void entries(AutoCompleteDropDown view, String[] array) {
    view.updateData(array);
}
```

`updateData` it's method which you must create in your `AutoCompleteDropDown`.
And in xml it's using same

```
app:entries="@{vm.genders}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<AutoCompleteDropDown
    xmlns:customNS="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.yourpackage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@={vm.title}"
    customNS:entries="@{vm.genders}"
 />
```

You can check this example [Android - custom UI with custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608464/android-custom-ui-with-custom-attributes)