# How can you associate an xml view to a java class?

Tags: java, android

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/menu_list_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Consider example of `RecyclerView` we put above code in xml and create its instance in java class like this

```
menuListRV      = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.sugg_rv);
```

After this we can control it anyway we want.

Now my question is how can create my own xml tag `<xyz></xyz>` may be with some proprties and associate a class `XYZ` to it.

UPDATE

I am getting the mediaplayer view but when I am attaching a xml to it I am not getting change infact I think xml view is not rendered itself.

```
public class ShortMediaPlayerControl extends ViewGroup {

    public ShortMediaPlayerControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflate(context);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Coming 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ShortMediaPlayerControl, 0, 0);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {

    }

    private void inflate(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.short_media_player, this, true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608464/android-custom-ui-with-custom-attributes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - custom UI with custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608464/android-custom-ui-with-custom-attributes)

Comment: You should refer this link https://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/how-to-create-custom-layout-in-android-by-extending-viewgroup-class

Comment: @Swayangjit can't we have xml associated with new class?

Comment: Yes you can have

Comment: I tried adding but I am not getting view's color change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create class, inherited from needed widget. In your case this is RecyclerView.

```
public class MyCustomRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    ...
}
```

And then you can use it in xml like this:

```
 <com.example.yourapp.MyCustomRecyclerView 
    ...
           />
```

UPDATE

Maybe late, but looks like i figured out what do you mean. So yes, you can associate your custom widget class with xml like this:

```
public class MyCustomRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
        ...
    private void init(final Context context) {
        inflate(context, R.layout.your_custom_recycler_view_layout, this);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: can we use xml with new class?

Comment: @RateM, what do you mean? If your class extends layouts or widgets - yes, you can use them in layout xml. Just try to create your class, add required constructors and methods (they can be different depending on the type), and then in your layout xml you can use your widget, where tag will be full package name of your class.