# How to get a string from attr with reference format type?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have my custom `attr.xml` document in which I specified `declare-styleable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="EditTextValidateablePreference">
        <attr name="errorMessage" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Then in layout I set:

```
<com.xx.yy.EditTextValidateablePreference
    ...
    ns:errorMessage="@string/validation_email_mail_server_invalid"
    />
```

And in `EditTextValidateablePreference.class` I get it with:

```
    String validatorErrorMessage = attrs.getAttributeValue(PREFERENCE_NS, "errorMessage");
```

`validatorErrorMessage` has a value like: `@2131099700`

How can I get its integer value to use it with:

```
context.getResources().getString(messageId)
```

?

Thanks !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's an excellent general answer which I recommend you to refer to: [Declaring a custom android UI element using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml)

In particular, you should use [Context.obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet set, int[] attrs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#obtainStyledAttributes%28android.util.AttributeSet,%20int[]%29) and [TypedArray.getString(int index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#getString%28int%29) instead of AttributeSet.getAttributeValue(...):

```
TypedArray ta = activityContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.EditTextValidateablePreference);
String theString = ta.getString(R.styleable.EditTextValidateablePreference_errorMessage);
ta.recycle();
```

Comment: Why should you use "Context.obtainStyledAttributes(AttributeSet set, int[] attrs) and TypedArray.getString(int index) instead of AttributeSet.getAttributeValue(...)"?

Comment: It appears that AttributeSet.getAttributeValue will not include themes in determining the result and will not resolve references for you (eg. "@string/my_label"). See [AttributeSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html)

Answer (score 12):

```
TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.EditTextValidateablePreference);
int resID = array.getResourceId(R.styleable.EditTextValidateablePreference_errorMessage, R.string.default_text);
```

And from this int, you can get the string by saying...

```
getResources().getString(resID);
```