# How to obtain the value for a reference attribute

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to implement a SeekBar that automatically updates a TextView, for the actual value, the maximum value and a minimum value. I derive from SeekBar and define 3 named attributes with the `format` being `reference`.

In the constructor, I get a `TypedArray` by calling `obtainStyledAttributes()`. `TypedArray` contains a lot of getters for every kind of attribute types. What I am missing is some kind of `Object getReference()` or `int getReferenceId()`.

How do I obtain the value for a reference attribute?

Edit:

I have an attribute definition for a class `MinMaxSlider`, that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MinMaxSlider">
        <attr name="min" format="integer" />
        <attr name="valueView" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

a snipped out of the layout definition looks like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/ParameterLabelLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            style="@style/ParameterSliderLabel"
            android:text="min. Interval" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/min_connection_interval_slider_value"
            style="@style/ParameterSliderValue"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.roche.rcpclient.MinMaxSlider
        style="@style/ParameterSlider"
        android:id="@+id/min_connection_interval_slider"
        android:max="3200"
        custom:valueView="@id/min_connection_interval_slider_value"
        custom:min="1"/>
```

Here, the `MinMaxSlider` should reference one of the TextViews above to display its current value there.

From within the constructor of `MinMaxSlider`, I can lookup the min attributes value.

If I try to lookup the valueView attribute as an integer, I always get the default value (0), not `R.id.min_connection_interval_slider` as I would expect.

Edit: the right function to lookup a `reference` seems to be `getResourceId`. The obtained integer id can be used to use `findViewById` later, when the overall object hierarchy is constructed.

In my case, I register an `OnSeekBarChangeListener()` and lookup the View in the callback, when the callback is fired.

Comment: I am not sure what you want. But check Applying Custom Attributes @ http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: Thanks, I've read that document several times, but found no example where an attribute was of type "reference". I want to reference one view from an other view. I thought that would be very common in GUI programming.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676469/how-to-get-a-string-from-attr-with-reference-format-type may answer your question

Comment: Thank you, but the example reference a string. I need to reference a TextView.

Comment: hmmm. Interesting....

Comment: Should this at least be possible?

Comment: Should be possible. Although i haven't tried this. I tried searching similar questions on stackvoerflow and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624973/android-custom-view-with-object-reference-from-attrs-xml-always-null

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I've used `getResourceId()` to get the resource id and used that id later to lookup the View by calling `findViewById()`.

Comment: I was about to try this myself. glad it worked.  got me curious..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't receive reference via findViewById in constructor. Because it is not attached to layout yet.
Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#applyattr

> When a view is created from an XML layout, all of the attributes in
>   the XML tag are read from the resource bundle and passed into the
>   view's constructor as an AttributeSet. Although it's possible to read
>   values from the AttributeSet directly, doing so has some
>   disadvantages:
>
> Resource references within attribute values are not resolved Styles
>   are not applied Instead, pass the AttributeSet to
>   obtainStyledAttributes(). This method passes back a TypedArray array
>   of values that have already been dereferenced and styled.

You can receive in another methods.
For example:

attrs.xml

```
 <declare-styleable name="CustomTextView">
    <attr name="viewPart" format="reference"></attr>
 </declare-styleable>
```

yourLayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <tr.com.ui.utils.CustomTextView
                        android:id="@+id/chat_msg"                           
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:gravity="left"                          
                        android:text="test"
                        app:viewPart="@id/date_view" />



                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date_view"                         
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"                          
                        android:gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

CustomTextView.java

```
   public class CustomTextView extends TextView {
    private View viewPart;
    private int viewPartRef;

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView, 0, 0);

        try {
            viewPartRef = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomTextView_viewPart, -1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        viewPart = ((View) this.getParent()).findViewById(viewPartRef);
    }    

    public View getViewPart() {
        return viewPart;
    }

    public void setViewPart(View viewPart) {
        this.viewPart = viewPart;
    }}
```

You can decide your scenario and modify this code.

Comment: Nice explanation. I am using format = "color|reference". Can you please tell how to parse this.

Comment: Hi @m__ ,
You likely to found in this list that you want: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray