# how to get AttributeSet properties

Tags: android, android-layout, attributes

Suppose i have a class which extends ViewGroup

```
public class MapView extends ViewGroup
```

It is included in the layout `map_controls.xml` like this

```
<com.xxx.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:background="@drawable/address"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</com.xxx.map.MapView>
```

How do i retrieve properties in the constructor from AttributeSet ? Let's say the drawable in the background field.

```
public MapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In the general case, you do like this:

```
public MapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    // ...

    int[] attrsArray = new int[] {
        android.R.attr.id, // 0
        android.R.attr.background, // 1
        android.R.attr.layout_width, // 2
        android.R.attr.layout_height // 3
    };
    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
    int id = ta.getResourceId(0 /* index of attribute in attrsArray */, View.NO_ID);
    Drawable background = ta.getDrawable(1);
    int layout_width = ta. getLayoutDimension(2, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    int layout_height = ta. getLayoutDimension(3, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ta.recycle();
}
```

Pay attention to how the indexes of the elements in in *attrsArray* matter. However, in your particular case, it works just as good to use the getters, like you discovered yourself:

```
public MapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs); // After this, use normal getters

    int id = this.getId();
    Drawable background = this.getBackground();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = this.getLayoutParams();
}
```

This works because the attribute you have on `com.xxx.map.MapView`
 are basic attributes that the `View` base class parses in its constructor. If you want to define your *own* attributes, take a look at this question and the excellent answer: [Declaring a custom android UI element using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml)

Comment: What should we know about the order of attrsArray?

Comment: getDimensionPixelSize throws exception, using getLayoutDimension works fine

Comment: I've also seen using `R.styleable.Whatever` in a few places in place of the hardcoded array (then using `R.styleable.Whatever_blah` to get the `blah` property, instead of a hardcoded index); could you add that approach to this answer?