# How to correctly read attributes from android namespace in custom Preference?

Tags: android

I am writing a custom `Preference`. I can easily read attribute values in my private namespace:

```
public MyPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray styledAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyPreference);
    mDefaultValue = styledAttrs.getInt(R.styleable.MyPreference_defaultValue, 0);
}
```

But I do not know, how to read android attributes, e.g. `android:defaultValue`. In all examples on the web attributes contain values, but I use resources like `@integer/my_number` so simply reading `attrs` does not work - attribute contains resource reference but not the value. android.R.styleable is not accessible, so I do not understand how to do it.

Comment: Wait if you have the resource references you can read its values? no?

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037101/how-to-get-attributeset-properties/8038712#8038712