# Programmatically check if a TextView's "textAllCaps" has been set

Tags: android, textview

Given a TextView, is there a way to tell if `android:textAllCaps="true"` has been set in the XML?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8038712/1245894

Comment: Thanks, the main issue I see with this is that `R.styleable.TextAppearance_textAllCaps` is a private style attribute, currently looking into accessing it

Answer (score -1):

Since the TextView's `allCaps` variable is package local you won't be able to access it easily. If this isn't for unit testing then I would suggest looking into [using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196207/2168085).

If you are trying to verify this through unit testing then you can use a library like PowerMock to use reflection to get it for you. The code would look like this:

```
boolean allCaps = Whitebox.getInternalState(textView, "allCaps");
```

Comment: This didn't work for me since allCaps is not a private field anymore (not on Android Oreo). Here you can fix it with I figured out you can check it with:
    textView.getTransformationMethod() != null &&
    textView.getTransformationMethod().getClass().getSimpleName()
        .equals("AllCapsTransformationMethod")