# Error when Declaring attributes in values\attrs.xml

Tags: android, custom-controls

I create a custom control as a android library. Everything is OK when i use this control in android project if i declare and use it programmatically, but i can't use this on XML so i follow this tut [Declaring a custom android UI element using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml). In the first step, I meet this error

```
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> myView, unable to find attribute a:gender
ERROR: In <declare-styleable> myView, unable to find attribute a:location
....
```

And also this on R.java file

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

this is my values\attrs.xml on library

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="myView">                    
        <attr name="a:location"/>
        <attr name="a:gender"/>        
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Am I missing something?. Waiting for your help. Thanks you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer for my own question. Just remove "a:" before attr name everything will be fine.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <resources>
        <declare-styleable name="myView">                    
            <attr name="location"/>
            <attr name="gender"/>        
        </declare-styleable>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Thanks! it works for me too!
But I'd like to insert mynamespace:myattribute.. seems impossible then, but looks like android is doing that, eg: <attr name="android:galleryItemBackground"/>
Do you have any idea? I've tried inserting XMLNS but it doesn't work, not sure whether it's not suppose to work or I'm doing it wrongly