# Define my customized theme for dialogs

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-theme

I finally understood what themes are and how to apply them to a dialog.
I would like to create a theme and I need help from you to achieve what I want. I basically want to create a theme to apply to alert dialogs and to dialogs throughout my application.

In my theme, I need to define the title background color, title text size, main body background color and main body text size. What items should I use?

Here is the starting code to prove that I put some work into it :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>     
<style name="myGeneralDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">    
     <item name="?"></item>     
</style> 
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF all you got is the XML you shown above, then if your questions is about this "?" sign in `name="?"` part, then only thing you can use here are **defined** attributes. In your case you can i.e. use `android:*` ones. If you need to define own attributes then see here: [Declaring a custom android UI element using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml)

Comment: Thank you, but where is the link? Exactly, I need to know what attributes corresponds to what. I mean I know about android:background, so does that refer to main body background or the title background? How can I distinguish

Comment: @Snake you need to find declaration of this attribute. It would most likely be `<item name="background" format="color|reference" />`