# How to add a new schema in the android ADT eclipse plugin

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt

I want to add a new schema in the android ADT eclipse plugin.

Please direct the thread to appropriate forum if I am posting at wrong place. I could not find ADT forum. Thanks.

Basically I want to add a new schema in android adt plugin for my personal experiments.

AndroidManufest.xml has following schema.

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

How can I add new schema (along with the above one) something like this?

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/foo

Thanks a bunch,

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2695649/1010868

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, currently. AFAIK, there's no forum for ADT.

What is the use case? If it's an important feature, you might be able to make an argument for it.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the quick reply. The use case is, I want to add few more attributes in the schema. If I add the attributes directly under "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" then it breaks android CDD. So if I create a new schema like "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/foo" I can add more attributes without breaking the CDD. I can compile the Apps with Android OS source code ( git cloned). But I can not compile the same app on eclipse. This entire thing is for personal use, never to release in public interest.