# Add custom attributes to existing xml Preferences elements

Tags: android, android-preferences

Is it possible to add a custom attribute to an existing Preferences element, like the following `myFormat`?

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="0.3"
        myFormat="Format 123"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:key="steering_threshold" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Or do I need to create a custom element as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml), like the following `MyCustomPreference`?

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <com.example.yourpackage.MyCustomElement
    [...]
```

Comment: It's not possible to add custom attributes to the default Preferences provided by Android. You will have to make a custom class, or implement one from the Gradle (which are also custom classes).