# Method like "instanceof" for custom views in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, instanceof, android-inflate

I inflate some layouts during running of App and store them in a variable of type `View`.I know that I can set a `Tag` for view after inflating it and check it to detect it's type,but is there another way to detect it?For example a method like `instanceof`?

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml or something else?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Oh,no... .It is in about creating and using customview from xml.But my question is in about how I can detect my customview is inflated from which layout?

Comment: @hasanghaforian you mean you want to get the file name of the inflated xml file?

Comment: @Pragnani Yes,if it is possible.

Comment: @hasanghaforian Nothing is impossible...just set contentDescription for your view, and identify your view based on the contentDescription

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 View yourView1=(View)findViewById(R.id.yourView1);

     boolean isMyView=false; 
        try{
           YourView yv=(YourView)yourView1;
     isMyView=true;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
     isMyView=false; 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    if(isMyView)
       {
         //OK it is yourView
        }
```

Comment: That do not work for views that are inflated from .xml files.