# How to extract current Android layout segments into their own custom control?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, custom-controls, abstraction

OK, I have a complete layout built; however, I am not really pleased with the long xml file that has resulted. I have a shorted version of the xml outline and designer view below. And I was wondering how I can abstract out each group of similar components into their own custom control.

For example, in the picture below, I have highlighted one such control that I would like to abstract out. Instead of it being a `LinearLayout` with 2 `TextView`'s inside with their own properties and attributes set. I would like to reference it via `<package-name.individual_song_item 
android:layout...> ... </>`. All I would have to do is set the first `TextView`'s text along with the second one via attributes in the top-level component.

**How can this be done?** I have the layout done and complete, but I don't like that nothing is abstracted away.

**So the expected results that I am looking for are (if you look at the right-side of the image. there would only be one `LinearLayout` below the image, and the rest would be `<package-name.individual_song_item>`)**

I have tried to just create a new layout xml with just the subsets of components, but I was not able to make it work when combining it back.

[image]

---

OLD WAY

```
<LinearLayout >

    <ImageView />

    <LinearLayout >

        <LinearLayout >

            <TextView />
            <TextView />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout >

            <TextView />
            <TextView />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout >

            <TextView />
            <TextView />

        </LinearLayout>

        ....

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

POSSIBLE PROPOSED WAY

```
<LinearLayout >

    <ImageView />

    <LinearLayout >

        <com.example.individual_song_item />
        <com.example.individual_song_item />
        <com.example.individual_song_item />

        ....

        <com.example.individual_song_item  <!-- example (possible!?!?) -->
            ....
            app:label="Group"
            app:value="Group Name" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you looking for properties window?

Comment: @Raghunandan no, I am talking specifically code here. I updated the question on the bottom to show what I want

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout eg.

```
public class IndividualSongItem extends LinearLayout {

    private String mSong;
    private String mSongName;

    public IndividualSongItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public IndividualSongItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.IndividualSongItem);

        try {
            // Read in your custom layout's attributes, 
            // for example song and songName text attributes
            CharSequence s = a.getString(R.styleable.IndividualSongItem_song);
            if (s != null) {
                setSong(s.toString());
            }

            s = a.getString(R.styleable.IndividualSongItem_songName);
            if (s != null) {
                setSongName(s.toString());
            }
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }

    }
....etc
```

You will also need to create an attributes XML for your new layout class.
For a full example of how to do what you're after look at the LabelView example in the ApiDemos.

It's also very well explained **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml)**.