# onDraw not drawing other components

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to create a custom `TextView`. I look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml) for my guidance as well and I made it working, though I'm still confused by why the other component is not being drawn, this is just more simple than the [reference guide](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) of android but it's not working in mine.

From the custom class I made (`CustomTextView` w/c extends `TextView`),
I try to add a `OnTouchListener()` and invoke the `invalidate()` method for both `this` and other component w/c is a `TextView` but it still not being drawn.

**CustomTextView.java**

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    TextView extra_detail;

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTextView);

        extra_detail = new TextView(context);

        extra_detail.setText("Hey!");
        extra_detail.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        extra_detail.setTextSize(2);

        a.recycle();

        //I also tried this in case the space isn't enough
        setMinHeight(80);

        extra_detail.invalidate();
        this.invalidate();
    }

    final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Here's my problem
        //both are not being drawn
        //even if I remove the other one and vice-versa
        canvas.drawText("Hey", 10, 0, paint);
        extra_detail.draw(canvas); //is this the right way to do this?
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        invalidate();
        extra_detail.invalidate();
        //still not being drawn
        //after the invalidation

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Hey!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        extra_detail.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

It seems I'm missing something here but cannot figure it out.

**Update**

I happen to `extend` my `Activity` with `ActionBarActivity`. Now with this kind of pre defined `Activity`, there is a `title bar` implemented and its hiding all the `canvas.draw*()` I made on the top-left-most of the screen. I figure it out after I invoke the `setY(10)` then the `canvas.drawText()` appears.

But I still have the problem of drawing another `View` in `onDraw()` event.

Comment: Probably you also need to override the onMeasure method and call the extra_detail onMeasure, or call extra_detail's requestLayout method

Comment: @CarlosRobles Still no good.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot try anything sice I am on my mobile.  Good luck!

Comment: @mr5 You also need to override onLayout, I think. onMeasure method describe size of element, onLayout - position. You not called onLayout for your detail view and it doesn't know where to be drawn.