# Can I inflate custom view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a custom view `BananaPhoneView extends LinearLayout` and I'd like to display it in a `ListView`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    BananaPhoneView bananaPhoneView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        bananaPhoneView = (BananaPhoneView) LayoutInflater.from(context)
          .inflate(R.layout.banana_phone, parent, false);
    } else {
        bananaPhoneView = (BananaPhoneView) convertView;
    }

    BananaPhone bananaPhone = getItem(position);

    bananaPhoneView.update(bananaPhone);

    return bananaPhoneView;
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight">

    <TextView
        style="@style/BananaListItemTextView.Wide"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/text_view_banana_list_name" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/BananaListItemTextView.Wide"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/text_view_banana_list_address" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/BananaListItemTextView.Wide"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/text_view_banana_list_city" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/BananaListItemTextView.Narrow"
        android:text="x"
        android:id="@+id/text_view_banana_list_brand" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However I get:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to com.example.banana.BananaPhoneView`

Is there any way to do that?

I used this tutorial: http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/

Comment: First, do not use `LayoutInflater.from()`. Use `getLayoutInflater()` called on your `Activity`. Beyond that, please post the contents of `res/layout/banana_phone.xml`.

Comment: What's the difference between LayoutInflater.from() and getLayoutInflater()? if he uses the right context is the same, also is better don't keep activity references into the adapter and getContext() will give the right context to use.

Comment: I posted XML. I don't have access to activity here, because the code is inside `Adapter`. I can also use `(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml

Comment: Shouldn0t this `<LinearLayout xmlns:...` be something like this `<your.package.name.BananaPhoneView xmlns:...`, instead?

Comment: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.example.banana.BananaPhoneView`...

Comment: @Funkystein, you helped me a lot. Can you please answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: OK, just a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:...
```

should be something like this

```
<your.package.name.BananaPhoneView xmlns:...
```