# EditText XML Design

Tags: android, xml

I'm looking to create an EditText that looks like the following & was just wondering if it was possible & if anybody might be able to provide example XML code to create the following.

Note: The cursor doesn't have to be blue, if it can be that's cool, but definitely not required.

[image]

Comment: In Android everything is always possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring a custom android UI element using XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml)

Comment: @Booger I have recently come to accept this. Wiser words were never spoken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an EditText with a custom background (the underline with the curved shape).  You would just use a standard EditText, and add your custom drawable (however you make that - either a PNG, 9Patch, ShapeDrawable, etc) as the "background" element.  The text label would just be a TextView you put in your layout above the EditText.

However, I would steer you to use the new "[TextInputLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog)" provided in the Design Support Lib.  This has a ton of built in functionality, and as a bonus, your app will be consistent with Material Design standards.

Comment: Yeah, this is actually what I was just looking at. Thanks for the in-depth response!

Comment: That new control is really great (you can probably still customize the background) - it provides great hint, label and error functionality out of the box.