# Screen does not draw unless setContentView takes the draw class

Tags: android, graphics, draw

this question is related to created a "draw/ scribble" application.

```
    draw = new Draw(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

If I want my buttons to appear, that may enhance the application, such as changing  color, the width of the stroke, clearing the bitmap/ canvas etc then I need the argument to take R.layout....

However,

```
 setContentView(draw);
```

Takes my custom view, where the touch listeners are. If I have this custom view on the application then my buttons do not appear, since the view is focused on the custom view, draw.

My question is, how can I add widgets to my application and still have the custom view that allows the application to draw.

Theory wise, will I have to dynamically create the buttons/ widgets on the custom view?

Comment: Put your custom View in the layout, just like you would any other View. [Here's a post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2695649) detailing how you can do that.

Comment: Mike.M my question has been answered. Admins, how can I close this thread?