# How to render custom view in designer?

Tags: android, xamarin, controls

I have created a simple custom `TextView`. The layout designer however, won't let me preview those custom `TextViews`, only `MockView`-Blocks are being rendered.

```
public class MainTextView : TextView
{
        public Typeface typeface;

        public MainTextView (Context context) : base(context, null)
        {
            InitializeView(context);
        }
     ...
}
```

Is how my class goes. I would like to preview my custom `TextViews`, but how can I do that?

Comment: Which SDK do you target? 24?

Comment: I never saw visual studio can show customer view preview. May be [android studio can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613628/showing-custom-font-or-view-in-preview-section-of-android-studio-xml).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the layout file, you can use:

```
<(insert your namespace for MainTextView here).MainTextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Hello world" />
```

That should work, you just have to put the namespace that your textview is a part of.

I would also like to note that I've had issues with Visual Studio failing to render my views no matter what I do, so in those situations there's not much you can do.