# How to create a piece of UI that can be used across multiple activities without duplicating the layout and business logic?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to create a piece of UI that can be used across multiple activities without duplicating the layout and business logic? Please provide some kind of example. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse layout [like this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html). Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289730/android-layout-is-reusable-component-ui-possible).

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively simple and there are a few ways to do it, but essentially you want to create a custom UI component.  The Documentation describes it a few approaches [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html), and there are a few tutorials out there as well as SO questions:

- http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2011/05/26/custom-composite-android-component/
- [How can I create custom controls in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046256/how-can-i-create-custom-controls-in-android)
- [Android - Writing a custom (compound) component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476371/android-writing-a-custom-compound-component)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) can fill the role you are seeking.